# Practical Example using computed observable with another context

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have been searching the web with for a while to find one example using knockout js computed observable feature setting the `owner` property to another context than the root context.

the problem is that I'm trying to access a foreach current context on the root computed property in order to calculate `product.finalPrice` property with the help of one property on the main vm as the following:

```
var product = function(){
  this.finalPrice = ko.observable(0); // setting its value on the main vm.
}; 

var mainVM = function(){
    this.taxRate = ko.observable(0.18); // tax property that is involoved on product price.
    this.CalculateFinalPrice = ko.computed({
    read:function(){....}, // reading value from current product context.
    write:function(value){....},
    owner: // I want to set the current foreach binding context here in order to change current product final price here.

   });
};
```

if you have any other idea to accomplish that concept using another technique, please list it.

thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about who the owner is. I also don't think you should attempt to modify the price of the products because you won't know if you've already done it or not. Each time you access the computed property, you will apply the tax rate again and again.

If you have an observable array of `product`s in your `mainVM`, then it can remain the way it is. However, if *each product knew the tax rate from `mainVM`, then it could calculate its **own** final price.* In this example, I use a mediator to link the tax rate from `mainVM` to each `product`. Then you can access either the untaxed price or the taxed price on any product at any time:

```
var taxMediator = new ko.subscribable();

var product = function(initialPrice) {
    var self = this;
    self.taxRate = ko.observable(0);

    taxMediator.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        self.taxRate(newValue);
    }, self, "updated");

    self.price = ko.observable(initialPrice);

    self.finalPrice = ko.computed(function() {
        return (+self.price() * (1 + +self.taxRate())).toFixed(2);
    });
}; 

var mainVM = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.taxRate = ko.observable(0);

    self.taxRate.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        taxMediator.notifySubscribers(newValue, "updated");
    });

    self.products = ko.observableArray((function() {
        return [
            new product(100),
            new product(300),
            new product(50)
        ];
    })());
};

ko.applyBindings(new mainVM());
```

You can see a **[working jsFiddle demonstration here](http://jsfiddle.net/44vXT/8/)**.

Comment: thanks @Cory for the replay, I have a list of product(not a single product) defined as observable array on my mainVM, so I need a way to access each product and modify its price with the help of a mainVM taxRate property, using a computed property

Comment: your soulotion is perfect for another task on my project :) , but the thing is that I want to access one product instance on self.CalculateFinalPrice property and get its finalPrice * taxRate - I need some how to access html view foreach binding context on the method CalculateFinalPrice.

Comment: @samih: What if each product knew how to calculate its *own* final price? I've updated my answer again. Read through my thought process in the paragraphs above the example.

Comment: its working fine now and I learned a new thing from this :), thanks a lot!